# Android Shaking do something after 3 seconds

Tags: android, seconds

I'm using this class for shaking event :

http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-shake-detection-listener

What I want is:  if user shake the device for 3 seconds in a row, than do something :

```
mShaker = new ShakeListener(this);
            mShaker.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeListener.OnShakeListener () {
              public void onShake()
              {               
                  Log.e("test", "shaking");
              }
            });
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the question. Any erorrs you are facing ?

Comment: No error, the class works fine. But when I shake the device, it detect it too quick . I want some delay or forexample after 3 seconds or 3 shacks do something @AlokSwain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this link

http://lfhck.com/question/303373/android-shake-detector-too-sensitive

it is using a `SensorEventListener` and the `onSensorChanged` event.